# Hyperterminal for XP problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hyperterminal

Is there any replacement program for HyperTerminal for Windows XP, to work same stuff ?
My hyperterminal in communications is empty ( don't know why and I don't have installation CD for xp anymore ). Please help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? PuTTY is a terminal application freely available for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is a free alternative to HyperTerminal.

Another free alternative is [Tera Term](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/ttssh2/).

Answer (score 0):

As a replacement for HyperTerminal, I can suggest RealTerm (http://realterm.sourceforge.net/), but you can't use it for dialing Modems or BBS Systems. (Read on the Homepage)